# Gaussian filter doesn't reduce gaussian noise in my python code

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering

**hi guys greeting**

I tried to reduce a Gaussian noise by using a gaussian filter of 5 * 5 kernel :

the gaussian filter that I have used :

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    image = cv2.imread('/content/Hand-gaussian-noise-2.png')
   kernel = (1/273) * np.array([[1,4,7,4,1],
                   [4,16,26,16,4],
                   [7,26,41,26,7],
                   [4,16,26,16,4],
                   [1,4,7,4,1]])
    img = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,6))
    plt.show()
```

the surprise is that when I applied PSNR calculation between the original image and the filtered one I found that the PSNR value between the original image and the filtered one is '31.585854382530492 dB' , while the PSNR value between the original image and the same image but with Gaussian noise is '30.247636779271325  dB', according to my knowledge this value must drop after the filtering, but it got higher, why ??

the code I used for  PSNR calculation :

```
from math import log10, sqrt
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
def PSNR(original, compressed):
    mse = np.mean((original - compressed) ** 2)
    if(mse == 0):  # MSE is zero means no noise is present in the signal .
                  # Therefore PSNR have no importance.
        return mse
    max_pixel = 255.0
    psnr = 20 * log10(max_pixel / sqrt(mse))
    return psnr
  
def main():
     original = cv2.imread("/content/Hand.jpeg")
     compressed = cv2.imread("/content/filtered_image.png", 1)
     value = PSNR(original, compressed)
     print(f"PSNR value is {value} dB")
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: (1) PSNR stands for “peak signal to noise ratio”, and is higher for less noise (amount of signal divided by amount of noise increases as noise decreases). (2) Blurring an image reduces the signal as well as the noise. It depends on the image content whether the noise is reduced more strongly than the signal or not.

Comment: thanks, sir, thanks so much, now i understand

Comment: @Cris Luengo
another question, would you recommend this method using a gaussian filter, I mean by using 5 by 5 Gaussian kernel to reduce Gaussian noise ?

Comment: There are many denoising filters. Non-linear filters tend to work a lot better, but it depends on the application.